# CImg compiler error

Tags: c++, c, image, image-processing

I want to integrate CImg library for image processing in my application. When i tried to compile sample application I got a compile time error. Error message is look like this.
**Unresolved inclusion:X11/Xlib.h**   When i change cimg_display variable in  CImg.h file from 1 to 2 for windows i will get following error. 
 **'va_list' was not declared in 
     this scope**
I change the value of the cimg_display variable to 2 from 1 manually in CImg.h file.

So please help me how to run my project using CImg.h file. 
Is Microsoft Visual C++ required to install on windows to run the sample of the CImg library?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need display capabilities of CImg, just define

```
#define cimg_display 0
#include "CImg.h"
```

before including the header file, and no third-party libraries are needed.